# Como tomar el valor de un select Angular cada vez que cambia

Tags: angular, html-select

Tengo este codigo en mi html

```
         <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>País</mat-label>
      <mat-select (change)="selectOpt($event)" required formControlName="country">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country.name" >
          {{country.name}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Como puedo tomar el valor del select cada vez que se seleccione algo diferente? Tengo el evento de (change) en mi mat-select pero no capta el evento

Comment: Puedes incluir un [(ngModel)]="event" y declarar la variable event en el modelo que recogerá el valor del mat-select

Comment: Se me había olvidado colocar pero estoy usando FormControl ya le agrege el  `formControlName="country"`. No se si funcione de la misma forma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utiliza **selectionChange** según la documentación de **[Materiral Angular](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api)** modificando tu código quedaria de la siguiente forma:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>País</mat-label>
    <mat-select (selectionChange)="selectOpt($event)" required formControlName="country">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country.name" >
      {{country.name}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Y la otra forma es que utilices **ngModelChange** para detectar el cambio puedes encontrar un ejemplo en el siguiente enlace: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44840735/change-vs-ngmodelchange-in-angular

Espero sea de ayuda. Saludos ;)